# Gradient Boosting classifier issue

Tags: xgboost

I am getting crazy trying to fix the issue of "name 'XGBClassifier' is not defined".

Any clue please?

My environment is Win 64, Python 3.7

Comment: Have you tried `from xgboost import XGBClassifier`?

Comment: Yes actually, this is the way I import it with.

Answer (score 1):

This can be very open ended issue. I would suggest you to check if Xgboost is imported or not , if not imported than is there any installation issue or not-

```
try: 
     import xgboost 
 except ImportError: 
     pass 
 except: 
     print("xgboost is installed...but failed to load!") 
     pass
```

Other points to be consider,

- Try to work in virtual environment which can exempt the other packages conflict with xgboost version.
- Check the  Input shape - there are times when this is the root cause of issue.